# how to add open button at the passbook

Tags: ios, passbook

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K81uU.png

you can see the pic,there is a open button,the pic is passbook pass,i do not find any api or pass attribute to finish it. at the pass.json

```
"backFields" : [
  {
    "key" : "extras",
    "label" : "Discount",
    "value" : "Your friends receive 50% off price"
  },
 {
    "key" : "phone",
    "label" : "Phone",
    "value" : "800-1234567890"
  },

  {
    "key" : "date",
    "label" : "Valid time:",
    "dateStyle" : "PKDateStyleMedium",      
    "timeStyle" : "PKDateStyleNone",      
    "value" : "2013-01-03T00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "key" : "terms",
    "label" : "TERMS AND CONDITIONS",
    "value" : "Lessons must be used between 1/1/2013 and 3/1/2013.  Appointments for lessons must be made no less than 48 hours in advance.  Customer must be able to swim."
  }
]
```

i am not find other key or label to finish it. can you help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add link to your application, I believe you should use the `associatedStoreIdentifiers` top-level key.

> Optional. A list of iTunes Store item identifiers (also known as Adam IDs) for the associated apps.
>   Only one item in the list is used—the first item identifier for an app compatible with the current device. If the app is not installed, the link opens the App Store and shows the app. If the app is already installed, the link launches the app.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html

Comment: Note that the `associatedStoreIdentifiers` key needs to be provided as a top level key (not inside the `backfields` array) and that the Adam ID needs to be provided as an integer and enclosed in an array, even if there is just one Adam ID.

Example:

 "associatedStoreIdentifiers":[123456789]